# Why is MySQL Event Scheduler Stuck Opening Tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I'm using *MySQL 8.0.21* From the MySQL Community Installer on Windows 10 updated to version2004 and for some reason if I create a event in the event scheduler, which calls a procedure once every second (regardless of what that SP actually does, I'll explain my test case) - my CPU maxes out and when I look at the active connections in MySQL Workbench, it stacks up a *ton* of worker threads which stall on the "Opening Tables" state. My PC freezes, I have to edit the event to be disabled, stop the MySQL process in Task Manager and Start the service again.

***TEST CASE***

During setup of a brand new server, I used all default settings, except I enabled the general log and I use the new 8.0+ mysql_sha2_password encryption (although I ALTER USER to mysql_native_password for phpmyadmin so that might revert it, I'm honestly not sure)

- I create a new Schema called "Test"
- I create one Table called
  "TestTable" has only one column called "column1" INT
- I then create a Stored Procedure "TestProc" which does "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
  TestTable;" Adjusts Priv.'s, DEFINER::Definer is root@localhost and
  Reads SQL
- And Finally I create an Event called "TestEvent" which does
  "CALL TestProc()s" Reoccurring every 1/sec, preserve on Complete, and
  definer is root@localhost
- restart server before event is fired.

Also, if I enable the event, or create it, it'll run without issue, it's important to note that the issue begins when the event scheduler is left on, and the event is left enabled, then the server is restarted from the services in task manager. Immediately the CPU jacks up to max and active connections show threads stacking up without completing.
Any clues are appreciated, I find no *actual* errors nor do I have any idea where to begin debugging anymore. I've tried skipping grant tables (but obviously that's not optimal, and didn't work).

[image: TestEvent] [image: TestProc]

I did find a hint when reviewing the MySQL 8.0+ docs

"If a repeating event does not terminate within its scheduling interval, the result may be multiple instances of the event executing simultaneously. If this is undesirable, you should institute a mechanism to prevent simultaneous instances. For example, you could use the GET_LOCK() function, or row or table locking. " from
[image: MySQL Reference Link]

However, when analyzing there does not appear to be any locks, nor should I need to implement such manually just for this test case (or my actual program)

---

***UPDATE***

---

Up to this point, albeit a rather niche bug, I do believe that is exactly what this is, and I have posted it on MySQL bug forum. [image: BUG#: 100449] Reference post is here: [image: DBA Stack Exchange - DDeathlonger]

Comment: Please post your TestProc source code and TestEvent source code for analysis.

Comment: I just added a photo, also I set the occurrence to every 5 sec. - the issue persists, it just eats up CPU at a slower rate so I can restart my server before it lags down easier.

Comment: Please consider keeping the 5 seconds recurring seconds and using an END time of 1 Minute so we can explore our 'Data We Need' as requested at www.mysqlservertuning.com - complimentary analysis.

Comment: I do need the event to persist indefinitely...

Comment: I also found an old post I made in DBA stack Exchange asking about the same issue several months ago and I got no response. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241261/why-is-turning-on-event-scheduler-maxing-my-cpu

Comment: Would you have flexibilty to Skype TALK with me?  Skype ID wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: Sure, I can do that, what time zone and time frame would work best for you?

Comment: In US Central Time Zone, (same as Chicago) top of hour, during daylight hours works well usually.  Thanks, Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer actually has turned out to be a bug which is reproducible - [Bug#: 100449](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100449)